# Set multiple cursor loaders with multiple adapters - Android

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I want to have two cursor loaders in my application fragment. Each one of them has different set of data and is used in different lists.

I found somewhere that with cursor you can use `getId()` method and then using switch do something. But, there is always method: `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);` after which can be something like this:

`adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0);`

This method is only for one cursor, but what if I have `adapter1` and `adapter2`? How can I determine which cursor is for which adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to implement callback listeners

```
public class Query extends  FragmentActivity {//do not implement callbacks
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(Constants.LOADER_DAILY_TASK,
null,dailyTaskResultLoaderListener);//note listener not "this"
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(Constants.LOADER_OTHER_TASK,
null,otherTaskResultLoaderListener);//note listener not "this"

private LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> dailyTaskResultLoaderListener
= new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {   
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bun) {     
        return  new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(),
Constants.DAILY_TASK_URI,projection, selection,selArgs,null); }
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) 
{...}
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursor) {...}};
private LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> otherTaskResultLoaderListener
= new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
```

....I think you get the idea

Answer (score 2):

Having separate loader callbacks is not necessary. The answer lies in the ID passed to the loader manager:

```
private static final int LOADER_A_ID = 1;
private static final int LOADER_B_ID = 2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_A_ID, null, this);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_B_ID, null, this);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    switch (loaderId) {
        case LOADER_A_ID:
            // return loader for cursor A/ adapter A

        case LOADER_B_ID:
            // return loader for cursor B/ adapter B
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
        case LOADER_A_ID:
            adapterA.swapCursor(cursor);
            break;

        case LOADER_B_ID:
            adapterB.swapCursor(cursor);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    ...
}
```

You can make as many cursor loaders as you like in this way and only implement the callback methods once.

Comment: You can't init more then one loader.
Moreover, you're creating unnecessary adaper (you can use the same adapter)

Comment: You can create as many loaders as you like, up to the limit of an int. That's the whole point of the loader ID.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is this. Remove the `LoaderCallbacks` interface from your `Fragment` declaration, then create two separate implementations of `LoaderCallbacks`, one for each adapter that you want to set up. Finally in the `onLoadFinished` method of each implementation set up the adapters.

```
public class ExampleFragmen extends Fragment { // Don't implement LoaderCallbacks here.

    private static final int LOADER_A = 0;
    private static final int LOADER_B = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_A, null, new LoaderACallbacks());
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_B, null, new LoaderBCallbacks());
        ...
    }

    public class LoaderACallbacks implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loader, Bundle args) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            // Set up adapter A here...
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        }

    }

    public class LoaderBCallbacks implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loader, Bundle args) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            // Set up adapter B here...
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        }

    }

}
```